# Style AG Grid's rowGroup

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, ag-grid

I am currently using AG GRID in my project and have implemented the RowGroup functionality for one of the columns,

Here's my code:
HTML

```
    <div id="myGrid" style="height: 400px;width:80%; display:none" class="ag-theme-alpine">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
     var gridOptions_PortCd = {
        suppressClickEdit: true,
        columnDefs: [
           { headerName: "Col1", field: "Col1", rowGroup: true, hide: true },
           
            { headerName: "Val1", field: "val2", minWidth: 200 },
            
        ],
        defaultColDef: {
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            resizable: true,
        },
        autoGroupColumnDef: {
            headerName: 'ColA',
            minWidth: 200,
        },
        groupDisplayType: 'singleColumn',
        animateRows: true,
    };
```

I'm able to feed the grid some JSON data, and all looks great (I'm not including the rest of the code as I do not think it is relevant to the question).

Now what's happening is, the Grid looks totally great, however I want to be able to style to rowGroup row in my grid because it is dark and I'd want it to just to be plain white.

here's what mine looks like:

[mygrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck5YI.png)

Sorry for the link only (SO won't let me paste image).

In essence, how do I set the COLOR of the ROW GROUP to something different, I've tried things like:

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-row.ag-row-level-0 {
    background-color: #dddbdb!important;
}
```

but that doesn't work. I'm not sure why it shows up as navy blue rather than just plain white or grey or something, but my hopes are to change it. Any pointers?

Goal is for it to look like this (In AG GRID website example)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RxpE.png)

I've looked on AG GRID website's documenation but they do not provide info as how to style it.

EDIT: I changed it like so, and now it looks like this:

```
 .ag-cell {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWG61.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chage the color of cells in RowGroup,try to use:

```
 .ag-cell {
        background-color: #dddbdb !important;
    }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Try to change the background color of `ag-cell-wrapper`:

```
 .ag-cell-wrapper {
            background-color: #dddbdb !important;
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: appreciate your help with this. Please see edit. It is coloring the row, but the Row group cell is still highlighted. I simply don't understand why for example the grid in your answer is all white, while the backgroup color of my group row is different color

Comment: Strange this is, if I don't have a row group, and just display the data in the grid, the entire grid looks just like in your answer. The minute I add a row group, background color changes to navy blue or w/e that color is

Comment: Hello,I have updated my answer,please try to change the background color of `ag-cell-wrapper`.

Comment: @awesome, i wish i could upvote. Thanks!